# Python: How to change the value of a function inside a class from an outside function

Tags: python, function, class, typeerror

Hi I am showing a subsection of my code. I created a function(propertyValue) inside an object class(CashOnCashROI). I then created a function (calculator) outside the class. I instantiated the class as "rental" and then tried to use rental.propertyValue() to call the propertyValue function outside the class.

What I am trying to do is change the value for "self.globValue = int(value)" from the calculator() function but I keep getting: TypeError: propertyValue() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. I was hoping someone could help me explain what is going on, how to fix it, and if there is a better way to do this? I am just starting to learn about classes so I greatly appreciate it.

Here is the code, it should give the same TypeError.

```
class CashOnCashROI:      
    def propertyValue(self):
        value = input('How much will you pay for the property? \n')
        while value.isdigit() == False:
            value = input('Sorry, we need a number? What is the proposed property value? \n')
        print(f"Your current purchase value for the property is: {value}")
        self.globValue = int(value)

def calculator():
    rental = CashOnCashROI()
    while True:
        rental.propertyValue()
        choice = input('<Other parameters asked here>, "Value" to change the property value.\n')
        if choice.lower() == "value":
            xvalue = input('What would the new property value be? \n')
            rental.propertyValue(xvalue) ### How do I change the value here???
```

Comment: `rental.globValue = …; rental.propertyValue()`, to literally answer the question. But that doesn’t make a whole lot of sense structurally, so it’s actually pretty unclear what exactly you’re trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to make an input in propertyValue() that takes in a value. Then I want to change that value in calculator() with a second input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the `propertyValue` function:
Setting a new argument (value) allows to pass a value from outside the function as an argument and skip the input function. If no value is provided, use the old implementation:

```
class CashOnCashROI:      
    def propertyValue(self, value=None):
        if not value:
            value = input('How much will you pay for the property? \n')
            while value.isdigit() == False:
                value = input('Sorry, we need a number? What is the proposed property value? \n')
            print(f"Your current purchase value for the property is: {value}")
        self.globValue = int(value)

def calculator():
    rental = CashOnCashROI()
    while True:
        rental.propertyValue()
        choice = input('<Other parameters asked here>, "Value" to change the property value.\n')
        if choice.lower() == "value":
            xvalue = input('What would the new property value be? \n')
            rental.propertyValue(xvalue) ### How do I change the value here???
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. This did fix the problem but now it is asking for `xvalue = input('What would the new property value be? \n') ` and then `value = input('How much will you pay for the property? \n')`. Asking the same question back to back. Do you have any idea how to fix this? thank you

Comment: remove the function call after while True: in calculator()